# Representing undefined result in MIT Scheme

Tags: haskell, scheme, mit-scheme

Imagine I have a function with a domain of all integers bigger than 0. I want the result of other inputs to be undefined. For the sake of simplicity, let's say this is the increment function. In Haskell, I could achieve this with something like

```
f :: Integer -> Integer
f x 
  | x > 0 = x + 1
  | otherwise = undefined
```

Of course, the example is quite gimped but it should be clear what I want to achieve. I'm not sure how to achieve the similar in Scheme.

```
(define (f x)
  (if (> x 0)
      (+ x 1)
      (?????)))
```

My idea is to just stick an `error` in there but is there any way to replicate the Haskell behaviour more closely?

Comment: Do you want lazy evaluation of the result?

Comment: Not really. I can always tack on laziness at a later stage if need arise.

Comment: Then Scheme `error` will behave like Haskell `undefined`, unless you intend to catch and examine the exception that is produced.

Comment: Hmm... How would I go about achieving something like what `display` does? It does it's side-effect of printing to terminal and it has an unspecified return value. How can I achieve that behaviour (the return value, not the printing)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is related to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/664373/176841) which has answers pointing out that in R5RS (which I guess MIT scheme *partially* supports?), the `if` with one branch returns an "unspecified value". So the equivalent to the haskell code should be:

```
(define (f x)
  (if (> x 0)
      (+ x 1)))
```

You probably already know this: in haskell `undefined` is defined in terms of `error`, and is primarily used in development as a placeholder to be removed later. The proper way to define your haskell function would be to give it a type like: `Integer -> Maybe Integer`.

Answer (score 2):

A common undefined value is `void` defined as `(define void (if #f #f))`.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that not all Scheme implementations allow an `if` without the alternative part (as suggested in the other answers) - for instance, Racket will flag this situation as an error.

In Racket you can explicitly write `(void)` to specify that a procedure returns no useful result (check if this is available in MIT Scheme). From the [documentation](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/void.html):

> The constant `#<void>` is returned by most forms and procedures that have a side-effect and no useful result. The constant `#<undefined>` is used as the initial value for letrec bindings. The `#<void>` value is always `eq?` to itself, and the `#<undefined>` value is also `eq?` to itself.
>
> `(void v ...) → void?`
> Returns the constant `#<void>`. Each `v` argument is ignored.

That is, the example in the question would look like this:

```
(define (f x)
  (if (> x 0)
      (+ x 1)
      (void)))
```

Comment: `(define void (if #f #f))` worked fine and is allowed in MIT scheme; `void` is not defined there by default either.

Answer (score 0):

Speaking specifically to MIT Scheme, I believe #!unspecific is the constant that is returned from an if without an alternative.

```
(eq? (if (= 1 2) 3) #!unspecific) => #t
```